# How to detect Save and Close vs Save in Tridion JS Framework (Anguilla)?

Tags: cme

How can I detect if the user clicked Save or Save and Close?

```
$evt.addEventHandler(item, "save", this.getDelegate(this.onItemSave));

onItemSave = function (ev) {//code}
```

Inside onItemSave function, ev.type = "save" and ev.name = "save" in both cases.

Comment: did you try for ev.type="save" && ev.type="checkin" for save and close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did in an extension where I had different behaviors depending on whether you clicked `Save`, `SaveClose` or `SaveNew` was to:

1. Register my commands as extensions of the existing commands:

```
<ext:commands>
    <ext:command name="Save" extendingcommand="ReleaseValidationOnSave"/>
    <ext:command name="SaveClose" extendingcommand="ReleaseValidationOnSaveClose"/>
    <ext:command name="SaveNew" extendingcommand="ReleaseValidationOnSaveNew"/>
</ext:commands>
```

2. Then on each of those methods that would be called I would set a variable identifying which was the original command

```js
CompanyName.Extensions.ReleaseValidationOnSaveClose.prototype._execute = function ReleaseValidationOnSaveClose$_execute(selection, pipeline) {
    if (!this.properties.InitialCommand) {
        this.properties.InitialCommand = "SaveClose";
    }
    return $cme.getCommand("ReleaseValidationOnSave")._execute(selection, pipeline, this.properties.InitialCommand);
};
```

3. Finally, on my "ReleaseValidationOnSave" code I would check the value of `this.properties.InitialCommand` and let the UI resume that command's execution:

```js
// This function is triggered by the event "finish"
// It invokes the original command intended by the editor
CompanyName.Extensions.ReleaseValidationOnSave.prototype._onResumeExecution = function ReleaseValidationOnSave$_onResumeExecution() {
    $evt.removeAllEventHandlers(this, "finish");
    var p = this.properties;
    $cme.getCommand(p.InitialCommand)._execute(p.selection, p.pipeline);
};
```

Basically this allowed me to "inject" my command before the UI's own, and also let me invoke the original command once my code was done running.